# WxPython Grid: Clear Selected Row Data Based upon Popup Menu Selection

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a WxPython Grid where I am trying to clear the data of the current row based upon popup menu selection. I binded the popup menu to the definition which clear the data but when I click on the selection nothing happens. Here is the code snippet.

```
def ClearCurrentRow(self,event):
    self.grid.SelectRow(self.grid.GetGridCursorRow(),True)
    self.grid.ClearSelection()
```

Any suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: By click on selection do you mean the row or the option and what do you mean by nothing happens?

Comment: I mean when I am in a particular row for which I would like to clear the data and when I right click and click the "selection to Clear data" , data doesn't gets cleared for that row. But if I change the self.grid.ClearSelection() to self.grid.ClearGrid() all the data gets cleared within the grid. Hope this clears up...

Answer (score 0):

Clear selection just unselects the row, you might find it quickest to delete the row and the insert a new one.

Comment: Is there any other way to clear the data without deleting the row?

Comment: `For col in range(NO_COLS): SetCellValue(row, col, "")`

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the row by setting its cells to an empty string.  I think you need to do this cell by cell -- I don't know of an operation that does this on the full row.